# Nested substitution in shell script ($ within a $ field variable)

Tags: bash, sh

I have a CSV file which contains the field names and values. The field names have given with a '#'
Eg.

#### test.csv

```
#field_1,field_2,field_3
1,axt,3
2,bss,3
```

I need to display the output like this:

```
heading_1=field_1
heading_2=field_2
heading_3=field_3
```

#### The script I have written so far:

```
headings=$(grep '^#' $arg_file)
echo "Fields name= $headings"

###### put a for loop to take in all headings as separate variables
for ((i=1; i<=$(echo "$headings"|tr ',' ' '|wc -w); i++))
do
    echo "Trial $i field"
    heading_$i=$(echo "$headings"|cut -d "," -f $i)
    var="$(heading_$i)"
    echo ${!var}
done
```

#### But this is giving me an error:

```
./script.sh: line 28: heading_1=#field_1: command not found
./script.sh: line 29: heading_1: command not found
```

What should I do to get the output the way I want? I am new to shell script and I am not really sure if that is even possible.

Comment: This is [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006).

Comment: btw, the `sh` tag is for POSIX-compliant shell scripts. Your existing code already has a bunch of requirements for bash and isn't expected to work with POSIX sh.

Comment: in `var="$(heading_$i)"`, btw, that's a *command substitution*, calling a string that starts with `heading_` as an executable. It's surely not what you want. `var=heading_$i; echo "${!var}"` is closer to being the Right Thing.

Comment: "${!var}" was still showing errors. I made it an array and it turned out okay.

Comment: Huh. It's a perfectly fine approach -- you can copy-and-paste the following to see it work: `heading_1="First"; num=1; var="heading_$num"; echo "${!var}"`